# How to change path to index.html (AngularJS) in GAE j2ee

Tags: java, angularjs, google-app-engine

I have a j2ee app running on GAE. There is that pre-generated index.html, which is called every time I run the server - let's say `http://localhost:8080`. But I want to write my own front-end using AngularJS. For that, I created the whole project with Yeoman and copied all the files to folder in my j2ee project.

Right now -> I can call manually the AngularJS webapp like this: `http://localhost:8080/webapp/app/index.html`

But obviously, that is not the way one wants to go. I would like to call it simply on `http://localhost:8080`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it took me longer than expected, but here's how I got it working using the welcome file:

Here's my folder structure:

[image]

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>So123</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>so123.So123Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>So123</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/so123</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>webapp/app/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Hope this helps.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#The_Welcome_File_List

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the root directory in the `appengine-web.xml` file. Full documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?hl=en#Java_appengine_web_xml_Changing_the_root_directory).

```
<public-root>/app</public-root>
```